# Syntax error in SQL syntax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web-services, mysqli

Here is the error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$userID' at line 1

This my code:

```
<?php
require('includes/config.php');
//if logged in redirect to members page
require('layout/header.php');
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    try {
        $userID=$_SESSION['memberID'];
        //insert into database with a prepared statement  
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO business (bus_id,bus_name,bus_description,bus_phone,bus_email,bus_website,bus_category,bus_address,bus_hours,memberID) VALUES (NULL, :name, :description, :phone, :email, :website, :category, :address, :hours), $userID');  
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['bname'],':description' => $_POST['bdescription'],':phone' => $_POST['bphone'],':email' => $_POST['bemail'],':website' => $_POST['bwebsite'],':category' => $_POST['bcategory'],':address' => $_POST['baddress'],':hours' => $_POST['bhours']));  
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('bus_id');
        //redirect to index page
        header('Location: memberpage.php?action=joined');
        exit;
    }
    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you set `bus_id` primary key

Comment: you have a  ) here that shouldn't be `:hours)`

Comment: you end your query with `:hours), $userID'` and i would guess the part `, $userID` has to go

Answer (score 1):

[SQL `INSERT INTO` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) has the following format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

As the error message says, there is a syntax error near near `$userID` in your statement. So, if we compare it to the above definition, you should move the `)` near `:hours` after `$userID`:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO business (bus_id,bus_name,bus_description,bus_phone,bus_email,bus_website,bus_category,bus_address,bus_hours,memberID) VALUES (NULL, :name, :description, :phone, :email, :website, :category, :address, :hours, $userID)');
```

Comment: If this is confirmed, the question should be closed as typo.